# Restarting R After Imputation

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am using the MICE package to do a multiple imputation on my data. I have 7 variables so the imputation took about 5 hours on my little laptop. This morning, I went back to work but needed to restart R. Now when trying to work with the new imputed data, I get an error saying the object does not exist. Is there any way to get it back without rerunning the imputation? Thank you!

```
library(mice)
dissdata_wide = mice(dissdata_wide, m = 5, meth = 'pmm')

#Diagnostic checking
dissdata_complete <- mice::complete(dissdata_wide)
head(dissdata_complete, n = 20)
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message you are getting and after what line does it occur? When you restart R all objects in your current working environment are lost unless you explicitly have saved them somewhere.

Comment: That answers my question. What a terrible lesson to learn :( Thanks for the answer!